# Understanding more about Telerik Platform

Tags: javascript, telerik

We are coming from .NET developers and trying to figure out this sample application Telerik Platform work utilizing Cordova (hybrid mode) especially for JavaScript.

The code is what we believe is Model for handling the activities. Is this correct? The syntax is a bit weird. It looks different from what we know. Can't figure out which one is method and which one is property.

It seems there is no more information about this type of Javascript. Where can I find more about this info beside Telerik site.

```
 /**
 * Activities view model
 */

var app = app || {};

app.Activities = (function () {
    'use strict'

    // Activities model
    var activitiesModel = (function () {

        var activityModel = {

            id: 'Id',
            fields: {
                Text: {
                    field: 'Text',
                    defaultValue: ''
                },
                CreatedAt: {
                    field: 'CreatedAt',
                    defaultValue: new Date()
                },
                Picture: {
                    fields: 'Picture',
                    defaultValue: null
                },
                UserId: {
                    field: 'UserId',
                    defaultValue: null
                },
                Likes: {
                    field: 'Likes',
                    defaultValue: []
                }
            },
            CreatedAtFormatted: function () {

                return app.helper.formatDate(this.get('CreatedAt'));
            },
            PictureUrl: function () {

                return app.helper.resolvePictureUrl(this.get('Picture'));
            },
            User: function () {

                var userId = this.get('UserId');

                var user = $.grep(app.Users.users(), function (e) {
                    return e.Id === userId;
                })[0];

                return user ? {
                    DisplayName: user.DisplayName,
                    PictureUrl: app.helper.resolveProfilePictureUrl(user.Picture)
                } : {
                    DisplayName: 'Anonymous',
                    PictureUrl: app.helper.resolveProfilePictureUrl()
                };
            },
            isVisible: function () {
                var currentUserId = app.Users.currentUser.data.Id;
                var userId = this.get('UserId');

                return currentUserId === userId;
            }
        };

        // Activities data source. The Backend Services dialect of the Kendo UI DataSource component
        // supports filtering, sorting, paging, and CRUD operations.
        var activitiesDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            type: 'everlive',
            schema: {
                model: activityModel
            },
            transport: {
                // Required by Backend Services
                typeName: 'Activities'
            },
            change: function (e) {

                if (e.items && e.items.length > 0) {
                    $('#no-activities-span').hide();
                } else {
                    $('#no-activities-span').show();
                }
            },
            sort: { field: 'CreatedAt', dir: 'desc' }
        });

        return {
            activities: activitiesDataSource
        };

    }());

    // Activities view model
    var activitiesViewModel = (function () {

        // Navigate to activityView When some activity is selected
        var activitySelected = function (e) {

            app.mobileApp.navigate('views/activityView.html?uid=' + e.data.uid);
        };

        // Navigate to app home
        var navigateHome = function () {

            app.mobileApp.navigate('#welcome');
        };

        // Logout user
        var logout = function () {

            app.helper.logout()
            .then(navigateHome, function (err) {
                app.showError(err.message);
                navigateHome();
            });
        };

        return {
            activities: activitiesModel.activities,
            activitySelected: activitySelected,
            logout: logout
        };

    }());

    return activitiesViewModel;

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this are javascript objects. They seem a little different because they are being created using what is known as the Functional Pattern. One of its principles is to emulate private data as everything in javascript is declared in the global scope except whatever you declared inside a function, which creates a new scope hence it cannot be seen from the outside. You can google it or if your willing to document yourself i suggest you to read "Javascript: The Good Parts from Douglas Crockford" as it contains almost everything to be considered best practices for javascript these days.